# how to compare two dimensional array with single dimensional array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

For clarity purpose Lets assume i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1234567
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 189818006457
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 10069992244808
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 100699922448
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 123454b
    [9] => 6
    [10] => 12345674b234
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 10
    [13] => 3
    [14] => 100699922
    [15] => 1
    [16] => 1006999
    [17] => 30
    [18] => 9
    [19] => 36
    [20] => 34
    [21] => 45
    [22] => 567
    [23] => 3
    [24] => 44
    [25] => 3
    [26] => 6788
    [27] => 15
    [28] => 189818006457371
    [29] => 17
    [30] => 123RT454b
    [31] => 5
)
```

And i want to compare it with the array below. So that when the values of the sub-array1 below matches the values of the array above, the system will print the value preceding the matched values in the single dimensional array above in a group. It will also check if the values in sub-array2 below matches the values of the array above, the system will print the value preceding the matched values in the single dimensional array above in another group-2 and so on.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 3
        )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 30
        [1] => 36
        [2] => 45
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 17
    )

)
```

Sorry am new to php but i have to do the project. Thanks

Comment: question not clear.

Comment: your question is think only clear to you, but for the others it makes no sense please update your question clearly what you is your desired output

Comment: Why do the subarrays have some values that repeat? How should that influence the result?

Comment: It shouldn't influence the result in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to first rearrange a bit the data that you have:

- Create a map for the array of subarrays, which for a given value will return the number of the group.
- Turn the 1D input array into an array of pairs

Then you can iterate the array of pairs and perform a lookup in the map.

Here is the code:

```
$input = [ 
    '1234567', 1, '189818006457', 3, '10069992244808', 2,
    '100699922448', 5, '123454b', 6, '12345674b234', 2,
    '10', 3, '100699922', 1, '1006999', 30, '9', 36,
    '34', 45, '567', 3, '44', 3, '6788', 15,
    '189818006457371', 17, '123RT454b', 5
];

$groups = [
    [1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1, 3], 
    [30, 36, 45], 
    [15, 17]
];

// First create an associative array that maps a given value to a group number
$map = [];
foreach ($groups as $group => $subarray) {
    $map = $map + array_combine($subarray, array_fill(0, count($subarray), $group));
}
// Now iterate pairs of the input data
foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as list($v, $k)) {
    $result[$map[$k]][] = $v ;
}
```

The `$result` variable will have three subarrays, one per group:

```
[
    [
        '1234567', '189818006457', '10069992244808',
        '100699922448', '123454b', '12345674b234',
        '10', '100699922', '567', '44', '123RT454b'
    ], [
        '1006999', '9', '34'
    ], [
        '6788', '189818006457371'
    ]
]
```

Comment: But if i may ask, how do i print the result to look like the one above @trincot

Comment: Oh, thanks it is working. I used print_r to print the result